# Memory configuration and exhaustion on Always On cluster

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, memory

I have a 2-node SQL Server Always On cluster hosting 3 SQL Server instances and configured as follows:

- Total server memory is 768G for each nodes.
- Memory consumption is 98%.
- LPIM is activated.
- Instance "A" min server memory is 102G, max 512G.
- Instance "B" min server memory is 102G, max 490G.

Recently, I installed a new instance "C" with min and max server memory set to 8G.

It seems that "C" is having a lot of problemes regarding available memory. At startup :

[image]

Sometimes connexion or AG failed with the message:

> *"There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query"*

Refering to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-17890-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15) there are several related causes.

My first guess is that instance "A" and "B" are still grabing all the available memory and when the new instance start, the OS reclaims a part of it.

My second guess is that there is no more memory for this new instance on the server, so most of it is sent to the paging file.

I'd like to have your opinion on this issue.

The only solution that I see here is to correctly reconfigure the max server memory for each instance and leave some free space for the OS.

I tried to stop the instance "B", freeing up a lot of memory and then restart my newly installed instance. There is a lot of memory available at the OS but the error is still happening.

Another point that i've note is that SOSMEMMANAGER clerk grabing all the memory.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance A and B will release memory when the system is under memory pressure, but it's not instantaneous.  So instance C may not be able to allocate memory when it needs to.  So yes, the typical solution here is to reduce the Max Server Memory of each instance so the others always have enough to function minimally.

Also you should also set LPIM on instance C, so its memory can't get paged out.  It's not a silver bullet, but it's better for SQL Server to be unable to allocate additional memory than to have its already-allocated memory paged out.

Answer (score 0):

You are overallocating memory on the server, the A&B instances max memory is 1002GB in total.

You dont state how many CPU's you have for the server but if you have 8 cores the max memory you should allocate in total [should be around 669.500MB](https://sqlmax.chuvash.eu/) and less if you have more cores. I would go a bit lower with the total allocated amount as the cluster services and AlwaysOn have some extra overhead

So if instance C uses 8GB of memory you have 661.308MB left to play with, giving you 317.427MB for instance B and 343.881MB for instance A, if we keep the same ratio between the instances.